# How to upload java selenium TestNG extent test reports on Google Cloud Storage bucket from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I have executed my tests on Jenkins free style job and post build the test report contains screenshots with logs. The same html file I want to upload on the GCS bucket from Jenkins.

I have installed google cloud storage plugin on Jenkins and I can upload the logs using Build steps "Google storage classic upload" but cant upload my extent reports.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set up the gcloud CLI on your host machine and then call gcloud commands from your pipeline the same way you would using a terminal. This allows for you to use the full abilities of the gcloud CLI without being restricted to the options the plugin provides. It is also more future-proof since the CLI will not go into any unsupported states as opposed to the plugin which may get deprecated.